# Change node author on user deletion

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a way to reassign all nodes associated with a user to another user when the first one is deleted instead of it going to anonymous?

To ask another way, I when I go to delete `johnsmith`, I am looking for the option to reassign all of `johnsmith`'s content to `janesmith`.

I know this functionality exists within WordPress.

Comment: Try this please https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations

Comment: Try this one may be possible duplicate https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138734/delete-user-and-change-content-author

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any way to do this without coding.

In code I would look at 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_cancel_methods_alter/7.x

to define and add a new method when cancelling a user. And

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_cancel/7.x

to act on the new method.